# How do I properly format an Azure Devops Pipeline API JSON request containing a variable in Python?

Tags: python, json, api, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to figure out how to properly format a JSON request passing a variable via Python in Azure Devops. It seems that the code does not escape the double quotes in the dictionary. When typing in the same variable via GUI, it works as expected.

Python Code

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# Api function
def auth_restapi():
    auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
    return auth

url = "https://[ORG].visualstudio.com/[PROJECT]/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0"
build_version = "1.2.3"
data = {"templateParameters": {"build_version": build_version}, "definition": {"id": 4}}
requests.post(url, auth=auth_restapi(), json=data)
```

When running this script, the logs show:

```
build_version: "1.2.3"
```

When entering the version manually in the GUI, the logs show the *expected* result:

```
build_version: 1.2.3
```

Is there any way to remove the quotes from the Python request variable?

Comment: techguyj Could you please show us the code which adding the file version in log ?

Comment: Updated the post to change the variable to *build_version*. This relates to the way Azure Devops handles API requests because it should understand the quotes and process them correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of troubleshooting I seemed to have resolved the problem. There were two issues:

1. The URL should be the pipeline url and *not* the build url.

```
https://dev.azure.com/[ORG]/[PROJECT]/_apis/pipelines/4/runs?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

2. The body should contain the word **variables**.

```
data = {"variables": {"build_version": {"value": build_version}}}
```

Comment: Glad to know it's resloved, you can mark your reply as answer and it could be helpful for others who encounter same problem.